# How to redirect after successful php if statement in ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, session, redirect

**PHP**
As you can see in the below PHP code I am trying the redirect the user but I am struggling to do it in jquery. what I want is if login statement is a success **login_success** then the user will redirect on myprofile.php but nothing happened.

```
    if($query)
          {
             $num=mysqli_fetch_array($query); //fetching all matching records

                if($num > 0) 
                {
                  //if record found
                    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = TRUE;
                    $_SESSION['cid']=$num['cid'];

                    echo  "login_success";

                }
                else
                {
                    echo "invalid email or password.";
                }

           }else
           {
             echo "something went wrong!";
           }
```

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({  
                       url:"sql/login_process.php",  
                       method:"POST",  
                       data:$('#login_form').serialize(),  
                       beforeSend:function(){  
                            $('#login_response').html('<span class="text-info"><i class="fas fa-spinner"></i> Loading response...</span>');  
                       },  
                       success:function(data){  
                            $('form').trigger("reset");  
                            $('#login_response').fadeIn().html(data);  
                            setTimeout(function(){  
                                 $('#login_response').fadeOut("slow");  
                            }, 7000);

                            if(data == "login_success") location.href = "http://www.example.com/myprofile.php";
                       }  
                  });
```

I thing I am missing something here.

```
if(data == "login_success") location.href = "http://www.example.com/myprofile.php";
```

Comment: Please make console.log(data) to see what data returns first.

Comment: What does echo back?

Comment: its echo login_success onto #login_response but i want to redirect the user to myprofile.php

Comment: Try removing the whitespace `data.trim() == "login_success"`. I'd strongly suggest yo change your logic to use a serialised format, such as XML or JSON as returning plain strings is far too easily broken by formatting

Comment: Are you sure that you're not getting any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: I guess no. there is nothing to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update
There seems to be nothing bad to echo the data as @Patrick Q mentioned below.
Could you try to trim the data received in javascript/jquery to check for unexpected whitespaces

```
data.trim()
```

If you want to add more variables you could do the solution below. (or if you prefer it)

You should not echo the result of the ajax. Instead you should return it as json

PHP file:

```
$ajax_result = array():
$ajax_result['success'] = false;
$ajax_result['message'] = 'Incorrect login data';

if(something)
{
    $ajax_result['success'] = 'login_success';
    $ajax_result['message'] = 'You were logged in. You will be redirected now.';
}

header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($ajax_result);
```

That would return the result as array to the front-end and you can operate with it by selecting variables with data.success or data.message etc.

Jquery/Javascript:

```
     $.ajax({  
       url:"sql/login_process.php",  
       method:"POST",  
       data:$('#login_form').serialize(),  
       beforeSend:function(){  
            $('#login_response').html('<span class="text-info"><i class="fas fa-spinner"></i> Loading response...</span>');  
       },  
       success:function(data){  
            $('form').trigger("reset");  
            $('#login_response').fadeIn().html(data.message);  
            setTimeout(function(){  
                 $('#login_response').fadeOut("slow");  
            }, 7000);

            if(data.success == "login_success") location.href = "http://www.example.com/myprofile.php";
       }  
  });
```

This is the most basic use. You can modify it to have protection to be accessed only from ajax queries and etc.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with responding with plaintext is you are only going to use a single text string.  It isn't as flexible as JSON, but it is also not inherently problematic.

Comment: You forgot to set the Content-Type header. PHP is going to claim it is sending HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. I do appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers and comments above. Honestly, I like Patrick Q Idea here and here is what I accomplished so far.

**Ajax**

```
  success:function(data){  
      if(data != null && data == "success"){ //redirect...
               window.location = "http://google.com";
    } else { //report failure...

                   $('form').trigger("reset"); 
                   $('#login_response').fadeIn().html(data);
                   setTimeout(function(){  
                   $('#login_response').fadeOut("slow");  
                   }, 7000);
              }
    }
```

**PHP**

```
          if($num > 0) 
            {
              //if record found
                $_SESSION["loggedin"] = TRUE;
                $_SESSION['cid']=$num['cid'];

                echo "success";

            }
```